# Get value form SimpleXMLIterator if has no children

Tags: php, xml, iterator, simplexml

Please check this code, taken from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmliterator.getchildren.php)

```
 <?php
    $xml = <<<XML
    <books>
        <book>
            <title>PHP Basics</title>
            <author>Jim Smith</author>
        </book>
        <book>XML basics</book>
    </books>
    XML;

    $xmlIterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($xml);
    for( $xmlIterator->rewind(); $xmlIterator->valid(); $xmlIterator->next() ) {
        foreach($xmlIterator->getChildren() as $name => $data) {
        echo "The $name is '$data' from the class " . get_class($data) . "\n";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

How to get values from all book nodes additional "XML basics" (in second book node) using iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you `XML basics` as output.

```
<?php
    $xml = <<<XML
    <books>
        <book>
            <title>PHP Basics</title>
            <author>Jim Smith</author>
        </book>
        <book>XML basics</book>
    </books>
    XML;
for( $xmlIterator->rewind(); $xmlIterator->valid(); $xmlIterator->next() ) {
        $xmlIterator->next();
        echo $xmlIterator->getChildren();
    }
?>
```

[:edit]
it will display both of books

```
$xmlIterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($xml);
    for( $xmlIterator->rewind(); $xmlIterator->valid(); $xmlIterator->next() ) {
        foreach($xmlIterator->getChildren() as $name => $data) {
        echo "$data<br />";
        break;
        }
        echo $xmlIterator->getChildren();
    }
```

Comment: Please edit code so it keeps output of the first book. Thanks.

Comment: do you want first book too or want to output first book only

Comment: both books, yeah first book too

Comment: Now it will output both books